# Draw a Bucket with multiple liquids

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, drawing, drawing2d

I need to draw a bucket and fill it with two different liquid colours (yellow and red).

I have got so far in a hard coded version but I need to be able to specify the % of the bucket filled, so for instance 50% yellow then 10% red.

I have never done graphics in C# so any and all help on this is appreciated.  I also need a cleaner way of doing the bottom of the bucket as it draws a black line ontop of the yellow in the below example.
[image: Current output of code]

```
private Bitmap drawBucket2()
    {
        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(200, 200);


        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
        {
            try
            {
                Pen penBlack = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);                    
                Pen penYellow = new Pen(Color.Yellow, 1);
                Brush brushYellow = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);
                Brush brushRed = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
                Point[] pts = new Point[4];
                pts[0] = new Point(11, 115);
                pts[1] = new Point(170, 115);
                pts[2] = new Point(162, 180);
                pts[3] = new Point(21, 180); 

                g.FillEllipse(brushYellow, 11, 90, 160, 50);
                g.FillPolygon(brushYellow, pts);

                pts = new Point[3];
                pts[0] = new Point(21, 180);
                pts[1] = new Point(91, 195);
                pts[2] = new Point(162, 180);
                g.FillClosedCurve(brushYellow, pts);

                /*outline */
                g.DrawEllipse(penBlack, 2, 10, 180, 50);
                g.DrawLine(penBlack, 1, 35, 21, 180);
                g.DrawLine(penBlack, 182, 35, 162, 180);
                pts = new Point[3];
                pts[0] = new Point(21, 180);
                pts[1] = new Point(91, 195);
                pts[2] = new Point(162, 180);
                g.DrawClosedCurve(penBlack, pts);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
        return img;
    }
```

Comment: The `catch` block is utterly pointless. If an exception is thrown, you'l *already* see a message about it. There's no reason to catch it and show your own message box. Additionally, you should never catch and swallow exceptions that you can't do anything about.

Comment: The next problem is that you're not disposing the GDI+ objects that you create (Pen, Brush, etc.) when you finish with them before the method ends. **You absolutely must call `Dispose` on any object that implements `IDisposable`**, otherwise you'll have a memory leak. (Yes, blah blah finalizer, don't care. You need to get into the habit of disposing these objects.) The best way to do that is to wrap their creation in a `using` block. Alternatively, you can just call their `Dispose` method manually at the end of your function.

Comment: @CodyGray The catch block is in there because there WAS an error that WASN'T showing on screen!  and this is far from the finished code, I do garbage collection once I know the code works fully

Comment: That's not possible unless you've got some empty `catch` blocks elsewhere in your code. Time for a code review... And no, garbage collection should be integrated into the design. It's not something you can go back and add later, or at least it shouldn't be. Improper memory management can prevent code from appearing to work properly, and introducing it later can lead to subtle bugs. That's a very strange design philosophy, not one I can recommend. It's not that big of a deal to type `using` when you write the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have manged to solve this one, I am posting the code here to see if anyone can still improve it before I accept this as the answer.

```
private int[] getPoints(int perc)
    {
        int[] pts;// = new int[4];
        double x_offset_left = (35 - 21);
        x_offset_left = x_offset_left / 100;
        double height = 135;
        double width = 178;
        double x1, x2, y1, y2;

        int margin_top = 66;//68
        int margin_left = 21;

        y1 = ((height / 100) * perc) + margin_top;
        y2 = y1;

        x1 = margin_left + (x_offset_left * perc);
        x2 = width - (x_offset_left * perc);

        pts = new int[4] { Convert.ToInt32(x1), Convert.ToInt32(y1), Convert.ToInt32(x2), Convert.ToInt32(y2) };
        return pts;
    }
    private Bitmap drawBucket2(int yellowval, int redval, int overval)
    {
        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(200, 221);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
        {
            Brush bRed = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, Color.DarkRed));
            Brush bYellow = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(75, Color.Gold));
            Brush bBlue = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Blue));

            GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
            Region r;
            Point[] points_yellow;
            Point[] points_red;

            int percentage = 0;
            int[] pts;
            int[] pts_full = getPoints(100);
            int[] pts_min = getPoints(1);

            #region "Yellow Region"
            // bottom curve
            percentage = yellowval;
            pts = getPoints(100 - percentage);

            points_yellow = new Point[3];
            points_yellow[0] = new Point(pts_full[0], pts_full[3]);
            points_yellow[1] = new Point(((pts_full[2] - pts_full[0]) / 2 + pts_full[0]), (pts_full[1] + 15));
            points_yellow[2] = new Point(pts_full[2], pts_full[3]);
            gp.AddCurve(points_yellow, 0.7f);
            //Console.WriteLine("curve : (" + points_yellow[0].X + ", " + points_yellow[0].Y + "), " + " (" + points_yellow[1].X + ", " + points_yellow[1].Y + "), " + " (" + points_yellow[2].X + ", " + points_yellow[2].Y + ")");

            //polygon
            points_yellow = new Point[4];
            points_yellow[0] = new Point(pts[0], pts[1]);
            points_yellow[1] = new Point(pts[2], pts[1]);
            points_yellow[2] = new Point(pts_full[2], pts_full[1]);
            points_yellow[3] = new Point(pts_full[0], pts_full[1]);
            gp.AddPolygon(points_yellow);
            //Console.WriteLine("Poly : (" + points_yellow[0].X + ", " + points_yellow[0].Y + "), " + " (" + points_yellow[1].X + ", " + points_yellow[1].Y + "), " + " (" + points_yellow[2].X + ", " + points_yellow[2].Y + "), " + " (" + points_yellow[3].X + ", " + points_yellow[3].Y + ")");

            // top curve
            points_yellow = new Point[3];
            points_yellow[0] = new Point(pts[0], pts[1]);
            points_yellow[1] = new Point(((pts[2] - pts[0]) / 2 + pts[0]), (pts[1] + 15));
            points_yellow[2] = new Point(pts[2], pts[1]);
            gp.AddCurve(points_yellow, 0.7f);
            //Console.WriteLine("curve : (" + points_yellow[0].X + ", " + points_yellow[0].Y + "), " + " (" + points_yellow[1].X + ", " + points_yellow[1].Y + "), " + " (" + points_yellow[2].X + ", " + points_yellow[2].Y + ")");

            r = new Region(gp);
            g.FillRegion(bYellow, r);
            #endregion     

            #region "Red Region"
            gp = new GraphicsPath();
            percentage = yellowval + redval;

            // Bottom Curve
            gp.AddCurve(points_yellow, 0.7f);
            //Console.WriteLine("curve : (" + points_yellow[0].X + ", " + points_yellow[0].Y + "), " + " (" + points_yellow[1].X + ", " + points_yellow[1].Y + "), " + " (" + points_yellow[2].X + ", " + points_yellow[2].Y + ")");

            // polygon
            int[] pts_yel = new int[3]{pts[0], pts[1], pts[2]};
            pts = getPoints(100 - percentage);
            points_red = new Point[4];
            points_red[0] = new Point(pts[0], pts[1]);
            points_red[1] = new Point(pts[2], pts[1]);
            points_red[2] = new Point(pts_yel[2], pts_yel[1]);
            points_red[3] = new Point(pts_yel[0], pts_yel[1]);
            gp.AddPolygon(points_red);

            // Top Curve
            points_red = new Point[3];
            points_red[0] = new Point(pts[0], pts[1]);
            points_red[1] = new Point(((pts[2] - pts[0]) / 2 + pts[0]), (pts[1] + 12));
            points_red[2] = new Point(pts[2], pts[1]);
            gp.AddCurve(points_red, 0.7f);

            r = new Region(gp);
            g.FillRegion(bRed, r);
            #endregion

            #region "Overflow"
            if (overval > 0)
            {
                gp = new GraphicsPath();
                gp.AddEllipse(16, 10, 165, 32);
                r = new Region(gp);
                g.FillRegion(bBlue, r);
            }
            #endregion
            r.Dispose();
            gp.Dispose();
            bRed.Dispose();
            bYellow.Dispose();
            bBlue.Dispose();            
        }
        return img;
    }

    private void fillBucket(int Yellowperc, int Redperc, int Overperc)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = null;
        pictureBox1.Image = drawBucket2(Yellowperc, Redperc, Overperc);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The "liquids" are two elipses with the space in between filled, so all you need to calculate is the heights and the left and right positions depending on the amount of liquid and draw from bottom to top (ie yellow then red)

```
// Upper Elipse and top Points for the filled center
y = HeightOfBottom + (FullHeight * (StartAmountFloat + AmountFloat))
x1 = Middle - (DiffenceOfDiameter * (StartAmountFloat + AmountFloat))
x2 = Middle + (DiffenceOfDiameter * (StartAmountFloat + AmountFloat))

// Lower Elipse and bottom Points for the filled center
y = HeightOfBottom + (FullHeight * StartAmountFloat)
x1 = Middle - (DiffenceOfDiameter * StartAmountFloat)
x2 = Middle + (DiffenceOfDiameter * StartAmountFloat)
```

The Bottom should be the lower half of an elipse, too.

Comment: Thanks Stephan, I'm totally new to GD in C# how would I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, don't have any code for you but I can give you an approximate workflow to achieve this. Basically you want to draw your objects back to front, so I would be drawing in this order

1. Draw the bottom of the bucket as an ellipse
2. Draw the bottom of the liquid as an ellpise of the same size, but one pixel higher
3. Now draw ellipses at each Y-pixel above until the desired % has been reached, where the end number of pixels is computed by the (bottom of the bucket) + ((top of the bucket) - (bottom of the bucket) * (percentage / 100)). You will need to widen the ellipse at certain points. This will create an aliased effect but don't worry, we are going to draw over it next
4. Finally draw the sides of the bucket and the top. If you choose a suitable line thickness you can cheekily hide the fact you hacked your way to glory :)

Last thing I'd suggest lots of trial and error. the more you do this the easier it will become! Good luck

Comment: Many Thanks for the heads up, its weird as you always draw top down in real life lol i'll remember to re-arrange the order.